# Symfony 2 Util SecureRandom and "null" character: how to manage it

Tags: php, security, symfony, passwords, md5

To generate random passwords in my application I'd like to use the Symfony Random generator component.

[The documentation says this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/secure_tools.html#generating-a-secure-random-number) about the possibility of a `null` character (`\0`):

> The `nextBytes()` method returns a binary string which may contain the
>   `\0` character. This can cause trouble in several common scenarios, such
>   as storing this value in a database or including it as part of the
>   URL. The solution is to hash the value returned by `nextBytes()` (to do
>   that, you can use a simple `md5()` PHP function).

So, my question is: if the method returns a `null`char, then the User will have to use it to write his password.

How can I deal with this, as I can't figure out how a null char can be write into a login form. Or am I missing something in the thought?

Answer (score 2):

You should never use the `SecureRandom` utility to generate passwords - it only ever generates bytes rather than characters (and even if you used the bytes as characters, half the ASCII character map are difficult to enter using a keyboard).

You could in theory use `base64_encode` on the data supplied by SecureRandom to generate a string that is enterable on a keyboard.

If you definitely want to generate random passwords then you're better off defining a corpus of characters you want to use then using something like `mt_rand` to get key offsets. E.g.

```
$corpus = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range(0, 9));
$password = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $passwordLength; i++) {
    $password .= $corpus[ mt_rand(0, (count($corpus) - 1)) ];
}

return $password;
```

These won't be "secure" random passwords but then that leads into a larger discussion about security policy and changing passwords etc.

Comment: When we have a stable 1.0.0 release, you can use [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) to get `random_int()` in PHP 5.

Comment: Note: When `random_compat` is stable, I think the Symfony team is interested in adding it.